# Как сделать окно сохранения данных с русскими кнопками в java?

Tags: java, save

У меня проект на `java`, я сделал опцию сохранения данных через `JFileChooser`. Начальство мне высказало замечание, дескать, проект под русскоязычного пользователя, кнопок `Save`, `Cancel` быть не должно. Да и окно сохранения должно быть привычное виндоусовское. 
Вот такое окно даёт `JFileChooser`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным помечено всё, что не устраивает заказчика.

**Вопрос:**  Как в `java` сделать окно сохранения с русскими кнопками и с русскими заголовками?

Comment: начальство такое себе. Писать кастомный выбор файлов (что пипец). Можно использовать JavaFX (там проще).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671868/how-can-i-add-localization-to-jfilechooser-for-a-locale-that-is-not-supported-by).

Фактически можно использовать файл свойств для перевода стандартных строк Swing. Просто позвоните

```
UIManager.getDefaults().addResourceBundle("com.mypackage.messages");
```

где `com.mypackage.messages` - полное имя базового пакета.

Comment: Очень интересно. Пытаюсь разобраться. Не очень пока ясно как сформировать пакет `messages`.

Comment: Там должны быть properties файлы.